# jquery traversing to find a parent's parent

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<li class="comment">
<div class="p_comm">
 <div class="avatar"><img src="/img/1.jpg"></div>
 <div class="c_auth">author<a class="del" title="delete it!" rel="19">x</a></div>
 <div class="c_cont w">what ever</div>
 <div class="c_time">12-23 13:22:15</div>
</div>
</li>
```

I want to find the parent li relative to the `<a>` in this section. I can't find a function to do this. I've tried `prev(),parentsUntil()` none of them can do this. Currently i have to use `$(this).parent().parent().parent()` to reach `<li>`. Is there a function to find parent `<li>` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or this:

```
$(this).parents('li');
```

Comment: This is dangerous if there are other 'li' elements further up the DOM outside the scope of the example given in the question

Answer (score 12):

You may use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). Try this:

```
$(this).closest("li.comment");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var p = $('.del').parents('li');
console.log(p);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hZY8R/

> The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the
>   latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree.

As you can see, when you use parents with a selector, you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) which will traverse up the DOM until it finds the element you're after:

```
$('a').closest('li');
```

If you were doing this the other way around (i.e. you had the `li` and wanted to find the `a`) you would use:

```
$('li').find('a');
```

Comment: Preferably he would also want an option selector for maintainability purposes

Answer (score 0):

`.parent()` by itself just refers to the immediate ancestor of a node, but you can also do:

```
var li = $('a.del').parents('li.comment');
```

to have JQuery go back up the DOM tree until it finds a matching ancestor node. In this case, `li` will point at the `a`'s `li` ancestor.

---

edit: forgot that `.parent()` only goes up one level, while `.parents()` goes up the entire tree. Both accept a selector argument, however.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a.del").click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest("li").attr("class"))
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(this).parents("li").hide();
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4yCux/1/